# ConcurrentModificationException issue

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to make a Brick Breaker game, but I'm getting a `ConcurrentModificationException` in this area.
I use Netbeans. This is in my `BlockBreakerPanel` class and it has the main information for getting my code to actually work properly. Exception location has ** around it.
I don't know why I get this exception and I'm wondering if it has to do with the `Arraylist` and if I somehow implemented it wrong.

```
public class BlockBreakerPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

ArrayList<Block> blocks;
Block ball;
Block paddle;

JFrame mainFrame, startScreen;

Thread thread;

void reset() {
    blocks = new ArrayList<Block>();
    ball = new Block(237, 435, 35, 25, "ball.png");
    paddle = new Block(175, 480, 150, 25, "paddle.png");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        blocks.add(new Block((i * 60 + 2), 0, 60, 25, "blue.png"));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        blocks.add(new Block((i * 60 + 2), 25, 60, 25, "green.png"));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        blocks.add(new Block((i * 60 + 2), 50, 60, 25, "yellow.png"));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        blocks.add(new Block((i * 60 + 2), 75, 60, 25, "red.png"));
    }

    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
}

BlockBreakerPanel(JFrame frame, JFrame startScreen) {

    this.mainFrame = frame;
    this.startScreen = startScreen;

    reset();

    thread = new Thread(() -> {
        while (true) {
            update();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException err) {
                err.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();

}
**public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    blocks.forEach(block -> {
        block.draw(g, this);
    });
    ball.draw(g, this);
    paddle.draw(g, this);
}**
public void update() {
    ball.x += ball.movX;
    
    if (ball.x > (getWidth() - 25) || ball.x < 0) {
        ball.movX *= -1;
    }

    if (ball.y < 0 || ball.intersects(paddle)) {
        ball.movY *= -1;
    }

    ball.y += ball.movY;

    if (ball.y > getHeight()) {
        thread = null;
        reset();
        mainFrame.setVisible(false);
        startScreen.setVisible(true);

    }
    blocks.forEach(block -> {
        if (ball.intersects(block) && !block.destroyed) {
            block.destroyed = true;
            ball.movY *= -1;
        }
    });
    repaint();

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && paddle.x < (getWidth() - paddle.width)) {
        paddle.x += 15;
    }

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && paddle.x > 0) {
        paddle.x -= 15;
    }

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: What is `blocks` and where do you update it?

Comment: `blocks` is an arraylist I made that contains various PNG images that make the blocks.
`blocks = new ArrayList<Block>();`

Comment: No sadly it doesn't @luk2302. I wish it did. I need a fix to the code, and what it should look like compared to what I have.

Comment: which line of code is the exception coming from?  what is the full stack trace?

Comment: Yes, it *does* answer the question in the sense that it covers what the exception is, why it arises and how to prevent it.

Comment: @luk2302 - except that nothing in this code that i can see removes anything from the `blocks` list?

Comment: i re-opened this question.  while ConcurrentModificationException does have lots of helpful answers already on SO, the relevance/application to _this_ question is not immediately obvious at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the crux of your problem is that you are using a separate thread to interact with GUI elements. That is a no-no in Java, the AWT/Swing UI elements are not thread-safe. You must do all UI interactions on the [event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). Generally, this is very straightforward for normal interactive situations. In your case, however, you need a UI task to happen periodically. When you need a periodic update to UI elements in Java, you should use a [swing timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). This will ensure that your updates happen in a UI thread-safe manner.

Comment: So what edits do I need to make to the code in this class specifically for it to work? What do I need to add in what specific methods?

Comment: @joey did you read through all the links i provided?  you need to stop using a thread and start using a swing timer